# Use "nth-of-type" kind of information as variable in css

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently learning CSS and found myself in situation where having found all these lovely "Shapes of CSS" (https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) I just had to fiddle with them. Especially with "Pointer" one (at the bottom).

The thing is, I would like to have a few Pointers next to eachother without any margin.

When i do this:

```
<div class="pointer"></div>
<div class="pointer"></div>
<div class="pointer"></div>
<div class="pointer"></div>
//also changed css to give .pointer a `float: left;` property
```

All the pointers would have this ugly white space at the intersection because of how `pointer:after` is defined (with white border-left). So what I did instead was:

```
<div class="pointer"></div>
<div class="pointer" style="z-index: -1;"></div>
<div class="pointer" style="z-index: -2;"></div>
<div class="pointer" style="z-index: -3;"></div>
```

Yeah, now it works. But inline style is such a no-no. So it got me thinking: is there any way to use information that given div is nth-of-type() as a variable to define its z-index? Something like:

```
div:nth-of-type(n) {
    //use magic to specify that `z-index = -n;`
}
```

Comment: with CSS no ... consider things like SASS/LESS ... or share full code as we may find some workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `@for` of  [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) to achieve what you wanted.

```
@for $i from 1 through 3{
  div:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
    z-index: -$i
  }
}
```

CSS Output

```
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: -1;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  z-index: -2;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  z-index: -3;
}
```

You can also try using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, you can do a lot of cool things using SASS. Glad to help.